# Statistics and Data Analysis How to interpret results of anova test

Tags: statistics

I have taken from a dataset the variables that I want to check: the work position(senior/manager etc) and a count of how many are in this position. There are 300 employees  of which 28 are in Senior Position and the rest are in various other. I want to test if the proportion of those in senior position is larger than the one in others. I have run an ANOVA test on a linear regression model with dummy variables for the job positions and what I get is this :
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0cFy.png)

From what I understand since I test only one categorical variable it is like performing a proportion t-test. What I do not get is how to interpret the results to decide whether the proportion in position A is larger than in position B.

Comment: As I understand the problem from your brief description (and the link to your results), I doubt that ANOVA is the correct analysis. // For how many individuals do you have counts of 'senior' and 'manager' positions and how many of each? // Please edit your question to clarify. // From what you say, it seems you may need to do a 'binomial test' to see whether the fraction of 'senior' employees is $1/2.$

Comment: @ BruceET Thank you for your reply. I edited my answer. The thing is I was wondering if I could do it without running a hypothesis test (I could use a proportion test to get the answer) but instead if I could get a similar answer by applying a model like ANOVA and reading the results.